# PyCharm doesn't recognize module gc

Tags: python, garbage-collection, pycharm

I am trying to use `gc` module and it works both in debug and normal runs. Unfortunately, PyCharm itself doesn't see this module exists and complains on it:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I was unable to install `gc` with neither `pip install gc`, not `conda install gc`, although it is working. I decided this package is built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences->project interpreter and search for it if it is a package (install if not already installed). Otherwise, make sure it's in your working directory (displayed as window header).

Comment: No, `gc` package is not in the `Project Interpreter` section. But `sys` package is also absent there.

Comment: I think this is a system specific bug or something. I just tried `import gc` on mine, no warnings or errors. Try restarting pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

If it runs, but PyCharm is complaining, go to `file` and do `invalidate caches / restart`.